# Cannot get React-Beautiful-DND and React-Virtualized to work together

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-virtualized, react-beautiful-dnd

Guys I've been trying to get this to work for actually a couple days and I haven't been able to figure this out.  I can get both libraries to work individually but I'm stuck on why it won't work when I combine the two.  I think I'm connecting them wrong somehow, I just can't figure out what it is.  Please help.

Tried to follow this guide [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/patterns/virtual-lists.md).  Source code for guide [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/stories/src/virtual/react-window/list.jsx).

[Here is a CodeSandBox of my issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-forked-9tpo2?file=/index.js:4195-4206).

Lastly here is a code snippet of the important parts from the CodeSandBox:

```
getRowRender({ index, style }) {
    const item = this.state.items[index];

    return (
      <Draggable draggableId={item.id} index={index} key={item.id}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <div
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            style={getItemStyle(
              snapshot.isDragging,
              provided.draggableProps.style
            )}
          >
            {item.content}
          </div>
        )}
      </Draggable>
    );
  }


 render() {
    if (this.state.items) {      
      return (
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
          <Droppable
            droppableId="droppable"
            mode="virtual"
            renderClone={(provided, snapshot, rubric) => (
              <div
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                style={getItemStyle(
                  snapshot.isDragging,
                  provided.draggableProps.style
                )}
              >
                {this.state.items[rubric.source.index].content}
              </div>
            )}
          >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <AutoSizer>
                {({ height, width }) => (
                  <List
                    {...provided.droppableProps}
                    height={height}
                    rowCount={this.state.items.length}
                    rowHeight={500}
                    width={width}
                    ref={(ref) => {
                      // react-virtualized has no way to get the list's ref that I can so
                      // So we use the `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref)` escape hatch to get the ref
                      if (ref) {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-find-dom-node
                        const whatHasMyLifeComeTo = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
                        if (whatHasMyLifeComeTo instanceof HTMLElement) {
                          provided.innerRef(whatHasMyLifeComeTo);
                        }
                      }
                    }}
                    style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
                    rowRenderer={this.getRowRender}
                  />
                )}
              </AutoSizer>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I managed to solve this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-forked-risye

You did not pass styles property in your rowRenderer to virtualize handle your rows in the right way.

Also you Autosizer was not growing past height: 0 because it's parent did not have any styles.

Comment: i moved on from this temporarily because i had a deadline to hit, but @Kira if i could give you more points i would!  the demo looks great and I more than likely will have to come back to this in the future.  i really think this should help anyone who's googled and tried to accomplish the same thing.. it wasn't easy!

Comment: @Person This codesandbox is missing, please fix it.

Comment: Hey can you please fix the codesandbox ?

Comment: I don't have the sandbox anymore and the original one does not open for me. Basically getRowRender has style parameter, you need to pass it to style property of the div inside.

Comment: `style={getItemStyle(...style,  snapshot.isDragging, provided.draggableProps.style )}`
Sort of like this I think.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still looking for an active sandbox with working prototype. Here is the post where I have answered and added the sandbox link

[react-beautiful-dnd doesn’t work properly with react-virtualized Table component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116012/react-beautiful-dnd-doesn-t-work-properly-with-react-virtualized-table-component)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to use both libraries together.

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-with-react-virtualized-om7zqr?file=/src/App.js)

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { List } from 'react-virtualized'
import React, { memo, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

const padding = 10

const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
  const result = Array.from(list)
  const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1)
  result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed)
  return result
}

const ListItem = memo(props => {
  const {
    item,
    style,
    index,
    provided,
    isDragging
  } = props

  return (
    <div
      data-index={index}
      data-testid={item.id}
      ref={provided.innerRef}
      {...provided.draggableProps}
      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
      data-is-dragging={isDragging}
      style={{
        ...style,
        display: 'flex',
        padding: '0 10px',
        alignItems: 'center',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        marginBottom: `${padding}px`,
        ...provided.draggableProps.style,
        backgroundColor: props.isDragging ? '#ccc' : '#eee'
      }}
    >
      <div>{item.content}</div>
    </div>
  )
})

const rowRenderer = items => ({ index, style }) => {
  const item = items[index]

  if (!item) return null

  const patchedStyle = {
    ...style,
    top: style.top + padding,
    left: style.left + padding,
    height: style.height - padding,
    width: `calc(${style.width} - ${padding * 2}px)`
  }

  return (
    <Draggable
      index={index}
      key={item.id}
      draggableId={item.id}
    >
      {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <ListItem
          item={item}
          provided={provided}
          style={patchedStyle}
          isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
        />
      )}
    </Draggable>
  )
}

const Column = memo(({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Droppable
        mode='virtual'
        droppableId='column'
        renderClone={(provided, snapshot, rubric) => (
          <ListItem
            provided={provided}
            isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
            item={items[rubric.source.index]}
          />
        )}
      >
        {(droppableProvided, snapshot) => {
          const itemCount = snapshot.isUsingPlaceholder
            ? items.length + 1
            : items.length

          return (
            <List
              width={300}
              height={600}
              rowHeight={50}
              rowCount={itemCount}
              ref={ref => {
                if (ref) {
                  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-find-dom-node
                  const whatHasMyLifeComeTo = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref)
                  if (whatHasMyLifeComeTo instanceof window.HTMLElement) {
                    droppableProvided.innerRef(whatHasMyLifeComeTo)
                  }
                }
              }}
              style={{
                transition: 'background-color 0.2s ease',
                backgroundColor: snapshot.isDraggingOver ? '#0a84e3' : '#74b9ff'
              }}
              rowRenderer={rowRenderer(items)}
            />
          )
        }}
      </Droppable>
    </div>
  )
})

export default () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const generateItems = new Array(2500).fill().map((value, id) => (({
      id: `id-${id}`,
      content: `content ${id}`
    })))
    setItems(generateItems)
  }, [])

  const onDragEnd = result => {
    if (!result.destination) return

    setItems(reorder(
      items,
      result.source.index,
      result.destination.index
    ))
  }

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Column items={items} />
    </DragDropContext>
  )
}
```